# Python クラスのCython化

Tags: python

`Python,PyQt,Pyside`で書いたコードを`Cython`で高速化
したいと思っています。`python3.5`,`cython'0.24.1`

独立した関数レベルでは、実現したことが
あるのですが、クラスそのものを丸ごと`Cython`化するの
は、初の試みです。必要がなかったので。
ちなみにメソッドを独立に`Cython`化
するには、もうそのクラスのメソッドからはずして、
独立した関数として、pyxモジュールに入れていました。
**何のために必要としているのかというと、

大量に抽象クラスをリストとして、取得したいと思っています。

　そのために、抽象クラスをCython化し、

一つ一つの抽象クラスにかかる初期化速度を

高速化したいのです。（簡略化しています。）**
　
これが、pure　Pythonのコード。

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import os
import sys
import re
import random
import another_module
class Haru(Saru):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Haru,self).__init__(parent=None)       
        self.IQ = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000  
        self.waru = Waru()
        self.karu = another_module.Tree()
        self.taipei = "taipei"
        self.malaysia = "malaysia"
        self.phillipine = "phillipine"
        self.bananas = [self.taipei,self.malaysia,self.phillipine]
    def eat(self):
        takeout = random.randint(0,2)
        get_banana = self.bananas[takeout]
        self.IQ += 300000000000000000000
    def sleep(self):
        sleeping = True
        self.IQ += 100000000000000000000
        time = 0
        while sleeping:
            self.IQ += 1000000000
            time += 1
            if time == 100:
               break
class Saru:
    pass
class Daru:
    def fellows(self):
        fellows = [Haru() for i in range(300)] 
class Waru:
    pass
```

このとき、単純なビルトインタイプがあるときは、どうすればいいのかわかるのですが、
　大体すべてをCython化しようとすればどうすればいいのでしょうか。
　例えば、こちらが上のコードをcython化したものです。（未実行）

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import os
import sys
import re
import random
import another_module
cdef class Haru(Saru):
    def __cinit__(self,parent=None):
        super(Haru,self).__init__(parent=None)    
        cdef int IQ
        cdef str taipei,malaysia,phillipine
        cdef list bananas
        # ここ！
　　　　 cdef Waru waru
        cdef Tree karu

        self.IQ = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000  
        self.waru = Waru()
        self.karu = another_module.Tree()
        self.taipei = "taipei"
        self.malaysia = "malaysia"
        self.phillipine = "phillipine"
        self.bananas = [self.taipei,self.malaysia,self.phillipine]
    cdef void eat(self):
        cdef int takeout
        cdef str get_banana

        takeout = random.randint(0,2)
        get_banana = self.bananas[takeout]
        self.IQ += 300000000000000000000
    cdef void sleep(self):
        cdef bool sleeping
        cdef int time
        sleeping = True
        time = 0
        while sleeping:
            self.IQ += 1000000000
            time += 1
            if time == 100:
               break
class Daru:
    def fellows(self):
        fellows = [Haru() for i in range(300)] 
        return fellows
    """IQ=indulgence quality"""
class Waru:
    pass
    """infinite indulgence"""
```

クラスは、さまざまなタイプの複合体です。
別のモジュールを利用したり、別の自分が独自で設定した
型を使うことがよくあります。
　O'REILLY の [Cython]を読むと、
　大体このような状態であっていると思うのですが、
　抽象化インスタンスの元手となるclass自体をCython化したほうがいいでしょうか。
　それとも、下のように、抽象インスタンスを取得する関数をCython化した
　ほうがいいでしょうか？(fellowsをCython化)

```
cdef class Daru:
   cdef list fellows(self):
       cdef list fellows
　　　　cdef int num = 300
       cdef int i 
       fellows = [Haru() for i in range(num)] 
        return fellows
```

としたり、特にこの場合は、
リストの中にあるHaruをすべて、Haru型として
宣言しておく方がいいのでしょうか。
　また、その場合いにはどう書けばいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deepな話題らしいので、中々回答が付きにくいようですが、少し調べてみた結果を書きます。

1.使っているPythonとCythonの版数を上げる

Python v3.6とCython v0.27の組み合わせで、Type HintsとVariable Annotation
　サポートにより、ほぼ純粋なPythonコードをCythonで適切にコンパイルすることが
　できるようになったそうです。
　どこの部分をCython化するか悩んで試行錯誤するより、全体を対処できるのでは？

[Variable Annotation と Cython でお手軽高速化](https://qiita.com/natsukium/items/99cffa5407aaf32a0b20#_reference-f9a4adbac6694d00946e)
　[Cython0.27で導入された型ヒント・変数アノテーション対応を試す](https://qiita.com/wrist/items/889696a507fbc8b392e4#_reference-ac8d0292f6b69af3ded9)

何か事情があって直ぐには対応できないかもしれませんが、覚えておいて損は無いでしょう。

2.実際に何が遅いかを計測してから判断する

釈迦に説法でしょうが、質問には書かれていなかったので。
　迷っているなら、プロファイリングで遅い部分を検出するのが、対処方法決定の
　近道だと思います。

[Pythonスクリプトのパフォーマンス計測ガイド](https://yakst.com/ja/posts/42)
　[Pythonプロファイリング基礎](https://qiita.com/masashi127/items/ca092c13e1300f4f6ade)
　[Pythonにおけるプロファイリング ― コードの高速化のために](http://postd.cc/profiling-in-python/)
　[Pythonコードのプロファイリング](http://shkh.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/08/16/221205)
　[Python: profile/cProfile モジュールでボトルネックを調べる](http://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2016/08/30/214718)
　[Python: line_profiler でボトルネックを調べる](http://blog.amedama.jp/entry/2016/08/31/213229)

3.高速化およびCython化を行うにあたっての他の人の知見

これも釈迦に説法でしょうが、後から参照する人のために。

Cythonによる高速化を行う際に、どの部分に注目すれば良いかのまとめ記事です。
　[深入りしないCython入門](https://qiita.com/pashango2/items/45cb85390193d97523ca)
　[深入りしないCython入門 -2-](https://qiita.com/pashango2/items/fed0a1c06c7077639edc)

高速化全般
　[高速化のためのPython Tips](http://nonbiri-tereka.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/09/01/072402)

Python/Cythonにcdef/NumPy/vectorなど色々組み合わせて計測実験
　[Pythonを高速化するCythonを使ってみた](http://kesin.hatenablog.com/entry/20120306/1331043675)

Comment: ありがとうございました。python3.6,cython0-27-3,に切り替えました。これで試してみようと思います。